# Set password on Zip file using DotNetZip

Tags: c#, zip, password-protection, dotnetzip

I'm using [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) to zip my files, but I need to set a password in zip.

I tryed:

```
public void Zip(string path, string outputPath)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddDirectory(path);
            zip.Password = "password";
            zip.Save(outputPath);
        }
    }
```

But the output zip not have password.

The parameter `path`has a subfolder for exemple:
`path = c:\path\`
and inside path I have `subfolder`

What is wrong?

Comment: assume path is C:\folder1\folder2\file1.txt
which folder do you want to zip and lock with password?

Comment: No, the path is a folder and that folder has a subfolder. I want the DotNetZip zip my subfolder and the files inside that. I able to do this, but the password not work. Is the first time I use that lib.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Only entries added *after* the `Password` property has been set will have the password applied. To protect the directory you are adding, simply set the password before calling `AddDirectory`.

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "password";
    zip.AddDirectory(path);
    zip.Save(outputPath);
}
```

Note that this is because passwords on Zip files are allocated to the entries within the zip file and not on the zip file themselves. This allows you to have some of your zip file protected and some not:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    //this won't be password protected
    zip.AddDirectory(unprotectedPath);
    zip.Password = "password";
    //...but this will be password protected
    zip.AddDirectory(path);
    zip.Save(outputPath);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the solution is good. But how can we hide the file names while encription?

Comment: @HabipOğuz - I don't think you can. The encryption is on the files and not on the zip container itself. The only way to achieve it that I know of is to double encrypt so if someone were to open the zip archive all they would see is another zip file.

Comment: @petelids, Hımm, thank you very much. That time, I will search a purchased one like WinRar.

Comment: @HabipOğuz - I believe 7zip can do what you want.