# How to set password in zip file

Tags: c#, zip

I use [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) for zip file in c#. and i can create zip file with password with this code:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()
{
    zip.Password = "password";
    zip.AddDirectory(path);
    zip.Save(outputPath);
}
```

I with using this code zip file my directory or file. but i want set password in my zip file.

So, I using this code:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("MyFile.zip")
{
    zip.Password = "password";
    zip.Save();
}
```

but it's not working.

Comment: It has already been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115705/set-password-on-zip-file-using-dotnetzip

Comment: this article using create zipfile with password. but i have zip file. I want set password in zipfile

Answer (score 0):

The following is a sample code for file encyption. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
// create a file with encryption
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
    zip.Password= "!Secret1";
    zip.AddFile("MapToTheSite-7440-N49th.png");
    zip.AddFile("2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf");
    zip.Save("EncryptedArchive.zip");
}

// extract entries that use encryption
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read("EncryptedArchive.zip"))
{
    zip.Password= "!Secret1";
    zip.ExtractAll("extractDir");
}
```

Comment: I do not want extract all file in zip file. I have one zip file and i want set password in file.